# After a force linux backup and reinstall, connect to a git repository again

Tags: github, git

i need your friendly help :), i just had to restore my linux distro due to it crashed, before that, i backed up all my projects folders and files. Now i have i completely new Linux installation and i want to connect again to github from my project folder but all project for github is new, i mean when i try to pull something the system says that i have untracked files and it has to be commited, i don't really want to push all my project again so (here the question), is it possible untrack those files for my local repo and continue working as if i've never restored my linux back?

Thanks to all can help me to learn this.

Regards

Anjrot

Comment: just clone from github

Comment: Did you have any local uncommitted changes before you backed up? If you want to keep them, you should commit and then pull. Else, you can use `git stash` to discard the changes, then pull.